# How to add power function to sigma

Tags: java, user-interface, math

I've written this code that computes the sum of the positive divisors, and all the values have to be to the power of a.

For instance:

```
sigma(0,14) = 1^0 + 2^0 + 7^0 + 14^0 = 4;
sigma(2,12) = 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 6^2 + 12^2 = 210. 
sigma(a, b).
```

I have tried different versions but I don't know how to add the power function.

```
try {
    int a = Integer.parseInt(input1.getText());
    int b = Integer.parseInt(input2.getText());
        int result1 = 0;
        for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(b); i++) 
        { 
            if (b % i == 0) 
            {  
               if (i == (b / i)) 
               result1 += i; 
               else
               result1 += (i + b / i); 
               } 
               } 
        result.setText(String.valueOf(result1 + b + 1));       
}
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your sigma algorithm?

Comment: I think the OP is referring to this, not sure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function

Answer (score 2):

In Java the `^` character means XOR.

The `power` function is provided by the [`Math.pow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-) method.

So `3^2` would be `Math.pow(3, 2)`.

If you wanted to implement it yourself for integers, you could do it simply like this:

```
double power(int a, int b) {
  int pow = (b < 0) ? -b : b;

  double result = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < pow; i++) {
    result *= a;
  }

  return (b < 0) ? 1 / result : result;
}
```

But I wouldn't do it myself. It gets a bit more complicated for floating points, and Java has a native underlying implementation which is much faster.

Comment: i know that, i am asking how to implement the power function to my code.

Comment: OK, not that its recommended to do it. I've added a simple implementation for integral (positive and negative) powers.

Answer (score 2):

`IntStream` delivers beautiful concise calculation.

```
static int sigma(int exp, int num) {
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, num)      // 1, ..., num
        .filter(k -> num % k == 0)     // Only divisors
        .map(k -> pow(k, exp))
        .sum();
}

static int pow(int k, int exp) {
    if (exp == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    int squareRoot = pow(k, exp/2);
    int n = squareRoot * squareRoot;
    return (exp % 2) == 0 ? n : n*k;
}
```

The power calculation can be optimized by not using `exp`# multiplications of `k` but square roots.

---

*For those interested in program transformation:*

`pow(k, exp)` needs only to rely on `exp` with recursion to exp/2 (integer division). So you could turn the code inside out, have a vector of divisors,
and operate on that.

Comment: Excellent answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement it without using `Math.pow()` you can simply follow the mathematical definition of the [exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation) for a positive exponent:

```
public static long exp(int a, int b){ //computes a^b
    long result = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        result *= a;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use Java lambdas to accomplish what you're looking for.

Taking an input and returning a List of positive divisors seems useful on its own.

Raising every entry to a power could be done easily with a lambda.

Keep the two functions separate.  Take a more functional approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code for you:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        List<Integer> listOfBs = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("Input your a");
        int a = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Input your b");
        int b = scanner.nextInt();
        int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(b);

        for (int i = 1; i <= sqrt; i++) {
            if (b % i == 0) {
                listOfBs.add(i);
                int d = b / i;
                if (d != i) {
                    listOfBs.add(d);
                }
            }
        }

        int sigma = 0;
        for(int e : listOfBs)
        {
            sigma += Math.pow(e,a);
        }

        System.out.println("Your sigma function is: "+sigma);

    }   
}
```